# SIR model differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the SIR model differential equations by separation of variables to get $S$,$I$,$R$ as functions of time , for example $I$ solved the Infected differential equation as follows: 
$$
dI/dt= BIS-YI, \\  
dI/dt = I(BS-Y), \\
dI/I= BS-Y dt, \\
\int dI/I = \int (BS-Y) \, dt = \ln{I} ⁡=  BSt-Yt+C
$$
Is that integration by separation of variables possible ? (Please answer)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. The integral $\int (BS-Y) \, dt$ is not equal to $(BS-Y)t+C$, since $S$ depends on $t$.

Comment: Thanks, but one last question is there a method that would lead me to have I as a function of time (t) other than using Euler method., ( i want to have an equation) ?Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Comment: You can derive some facts analytically, but as far as a know there is no known explicit formula for $I(t)$. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model_without_vital_dynamics. (If you want a numerical solution, there are of course *many* other options besides the Euler method.)